# Trying to apply "-webkit-box" into "display" property in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a weird issue. I am using the Bones theme in Wordpress, and simply trying to put a style on my home page menu.

The site is h*Xp://www.advanceditsolutions.net/nearitest/

The CSS I’m trying to use is this:

```
.home ul#menu-pages {
    display: -webkit-box;
}
```

I have it in both of the media query sections, min-width:481, and min-width:768. I’ve also tried it outside of the media query scope, no luck. I can’t figure out why it doesn’t get picked up though. I inspect it on the site, and nowhere do I see the display CSS.

What sucks is, the placement is fine is most browsers, but Chrome it's all jacked up.

:: scratches head ::

Answer (score 2):

1) First of all, you're using vendor prefix `-webkit-` that will work just on specific browser(s).

2) Check if the value is correct. [Here is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) the list of all possible values for `display` property. **Are you sure** that `-webkit-box` is a correct value that can be applied to `display`?

Maybe instead of telling that the CSS you want to apply, doesn't work, share the larger context, a screenshot and tell us exactly what you want to achieve.

3) Do you use some developer tools, like Chrome Dev Tools, Firebug or something similar to apply and test styles? It's handy and can save you bunch of time trying to figure out what's wrong...

Comment: 1) I intended that. I need it to work only on Chrome, other browsers are fine.

2) The value is correct, and can be used with display, and in this case.

I apologize, I figured one would just click one of the links to another page to check what it should look like. I did specify that it was only the home page menu that was the trouble.

3) This is how I found that -webkit-box will work just fine. Using Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: Any thoughts about how to actually fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can see it is working within the min-width:768 media query. You only have it included once in the stylesheet though from what i can see.

Two critical issues here are:
1) This css will only target the home page because you've used '.home' as part of your selector.
2) You've used the '-webkit' vendor prefix so it'll only work in browsers that run on that engine and support that property. I would recommend against this. You are probably better off using a flex display type.

Comment: It is vendor specific to Chrome though, no? -webkit, I mean.

You're right, I sort of had to hack my way through this a bit. The original designers had suppressed the menu from the home page in the header.php file. Even when I took out the !is_front_page() function, the menu still did not sit right, though using Chrome Dev Tools, I was able to add 'display: -webkit-box;' to fix the issue in Chrome. Other browsers seemed to render fine.

Comment: I did just check my stylesheet again, too. I did have it in both media queries. Not sure why it only shows one.

Comment: In terms of major browsers it is Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I just re-checked your 'style.css', it's definitely only there once. If you want it to be used from 481 and up, you should be able to remove it from the current media query and only use it inside the 481px media query.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to want to take it.

Maybe if I explain how I got to this point it will make things more clear. I very well might be missing something simple.
 
I made the PHP change I mentioned before, letting the menu show on the home page. This made it look like it is now, sort of lined up vertically, instead of horizontally like the other pages. So I messed around with the menu elements in Chrome Dev Tools, and when I inserted display: -webkit-box; on the UL element it 'fixed' it.

Comment: My main issue was trying to edit the actual CSS/HTML of the menu itself. So I created a new PHP function specifically for the home page menu, and attached the above CSS code to it as well.

Still nothing lol And I don't see it in Dev Tools when I look at the UL element. I don't get it.

Comment: You will see it in dev tools when you look at the ul element when your window is greater than 768px wide and you are on the home page. I see it.